# How to make a get request in mongoDB for a nested array finding by postId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How do i get a single comment in the nested array "comments" in this case by the postId?

```
{
    "_id": "64200557af767187bcbcfc6c",
    "username": "ascarids",
    "usersAt": "@osteoids",
    "comments": [
        {
            "username": "osteoids",
            "photo": "",
            "comments": "Now it would def work.",
            "usersAt": "@osteoids",
            "postId": "64200557af767187bcbcfc6c",
            "createdAt": 1682006033770
        },
        {
            "username": "osteoids",
            "photo": "",
            "comments": "Now let's try something",
            "usersAt": "@osteoids",
            "postId": "64200557af767187bcbcuy6c",
            "createdAt": 1683486129151,
            "like": [],
            "newId": "11621edadd13e67431d40e45"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-03-26T08:41:59.187Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-05-07T19:02:50.015Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I've tried writing it this way, but it's not working, and I keep seeing things to try like $elemMatch and $map and some other methods. i'm not sure whether im not accesing the array deeply enough or if i just wrote it the wrong way.

```
router.get(`:id/:postId`, async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const postId = req.params.postId
  let comments;
  try {
    comments = await Post.findById({comments: {postId: postId}})
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
  if (!comments) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "No posts found" });
  }

  return res.status(200).json({ comments });
})
```

But what i really want is the nested array

```
//Writing it this way is what returns the above json format
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use projection, which is the second `{}` in the `find` query:

```
comments = await Post.find(
  {_id: _id, comments: {$elemMatch: {postId: req.params.postId}}},
  {"comments.$": 1}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2W79CYxB_CP)

- Notice that mongoose `findById` expects the document's `_id` and not a nested id. On this option you are using also the `postId` so you can later project it

Comment: is my route correct though?, router.get(`:id/:postId`) would that work?

Comment: You are currently using `findById`, but not providing the document `_id`...So this can't work